# Time Complexity of HackerRank Diagonal Difference

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

**Can anyone help me identify the time complexity of the following code?**

Background: this is a [HackerRank algorithm problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference/problem) where the editorial section lists the solution with a time complexity of O(n^2) but I think its O(n).

I believe its O(n) because we're only using one loop to traverse the 2 dimensional array and are not using nested loops and only looping over the array once.

**Am I correct or am I missing something?**

**Solution**

```
//arr is a 2 dimensional array containing an equal number of rows and columns
function diagonalDifference(arr) {
  let diff = 0;
  const length = arr.length - 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    diff += arr[i][i] - arr[i][length - i];
  }
  return Math.abs(diff);
}
```

**Problem**

Given a square matrix (AKA 2D Array), calculate the absolute difference between the sums of its diagonals.

For example, the square matrix ***arr*** is shown below:

1 2 3
4 5 6
9 8 9

The left-to-right diagonal = 1 + 5 + 9 = 15. The right to left diagonal = 3 + 5 + 9 = 17. Their absolute difference is |15 - 17| = 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I correct or am I missing something?

You are right, but I think their categorization of `O(n^2)` may be due to the interpretation wherein `n` refers to the `n` of the input (i.e. the side-length of the matrix).  In this case, the number of elements in the matrix itself is exactly `n^2`, and thus any solution (since any solution must read in all `n^2` inputs) is `Ω(n^2)` (where `Ω` roughly means "at least").

Your categorization of the solution as `O(n)` is correct if we say that `n` refers to the size of the whole input matrix.

Comment: Thanks Kevin!  I think that makes sense, they may have been framing the n as they did in the question as opposed to the overall input.  Thanks so much for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity of the code is `O(n)` where is the length of the matrix. As you have correctly said the loop is running only once and that too equals the number of rows/ columns viz the length of the matrix. there are no nested loops. So the time complexity is definitely, O(n) for all the cases best, worst, avg.

Comment: Thanks @Ashish thanks, I completely agree!  Thanks for taking the time to explain it to me!

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
function diagonalDifference(arr) {
let leftDiagSum = 0;
let rightDiagSum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    leftDiagSum += arr[i][i];
    rightDiagSum += arr[i][arr[i].length - (i + 1)];
}
let sum = Math.abs(leftDiagSum - rightDiagSum);
return sum;
```

}

Comment: Original poster requested help with deciding the time-complexity of the given algorithm. I don't think this answers that question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:

`

```
function diagonalDifference(arr) {
    let firstDiagonalSum = arr[0][0] + arr[1][1] + arr[2][2];
    let secondDiagonalSum = arr[0][2] + arr[1][1] + arr[2][0];
    let result = (secondDiagonalSum) - (firstDiagonalSum);
    
    return result;
}`
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

in python :

```
def diagonalDifference(arr):
    
    d1 = 0
    d2 = 0
    n = len(arr)

    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, n):
            
            if (i == j):
                d1 += arr[i][j]
    
            if (i == n - j - 1):
                d2 += arr[i][j]
        
    return abs(d1 - d2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this way as well**

```
def diagonalDifference(arr):
    lr_diag = 0
    rl_diag = 0
    
    for i in range(len(arr)):
      for j in range(len(arr)):
        if i==j:
          lr_diag+=arr[i][j]
        if i==abs(j-(len(arr)-1)):
          rl_diag += arr[i][j]
    return abs(lr_diag - rl_diag)
```